# Visual Studio 2017 - 'normal' html/php site, minify, versioning, bootstrap, etc

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I am not new to web dev (almost 20 years now), but thinking about converting to MS Visual Studio Community 2017 and am clueless as to where to begin.  I have been using MS Expresison Web (don't laugh, it does what it needs to) and Koala running in the back for minifying/bundling css, js, scss, etc.

I've looked for guides, but haven't found anything that actually explains the process.  I read things about Gulp, Grunt, pre and post processing, batch files, etc, etc, but that is all foreign to me.  I'm sure it won't be a problem picking it up quickly just need something to read how this is done or see how it is done to get me started.

I downloaded MS Visual Studio 2017 (the free one they offer) and selected the 'ASP.NET and web development'.  I open it, select new project and don't even know what to choose as it is all languages I won't be using.  I just want a regular bootstrap site, html, php, css, scss, js, and so on.

What I would like to do :

- html, php, css, xml, js, etc
- bundle css and js files if needed into single file
- scss files
- minify html, js, css only on upload or create new files in different location of upload... I would like to keep the 'originals' and work on those only
- would like to be able to add versioning when I link css and js files in the pages... it would be awesome if I could do something like `<link href="/assets/css/bootstrap-%%TIMESTAMP%%.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">` where timestamp would be replaced by unix timestamp at the time the page was uploaded.  This is kind of what I do now, but with filemtime in php and have some code in htaccess to go along with that.  This makes sure visitors get the latest file, but in reality it still serves bootstrap.css on the server.  I can change bootstrap.css as much as I want and when it changes they get the latest 'version' and if not it will be cached.

It seems most of these are possible, but I have no idea where to begin being completely new to VS.  I can't even start a 'site' as it stands right now as I don't know what selection to start with lol.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think the key difference you will find is that Visual Studio is highly geared towards developing ASP.NET webforms and ASP.NET MVC projects.

Visual studio does not natively support PHP.
There are additional packages that need to be downloaded to get PHP working with Visual Studio. One of these packages is called **Devsence PHP tools**.

> licensing of **Visual Studio Express** does not allow the extensibility. Thus PHP Tools does not support VS Express editions.[Source Devsense](https://docs.devsense.com/)

With that being said, you have limited options to integrate PHP, although in my opinion I wouldn't advise you go down this road. Visual Studio was not designed for developing PHP code. Yes, some companies may have invested into integrating PHP support but Visual Studio is made for .NET.

The problem you will face moving forward is that you need a high level of programming knowledge in order to transition from pure web development (the skills you already have) to one that incorporates a server side language as you'll no longer just be working with css, js, html ajax etc but you will also face the complexities of integrating these files with server side code.

On top of that you'll face other complexities that you would not have faced in MS Expressions(i.e building, debugging and deploying your project, making sure your references and source files are linked correctly, the list goes on).

What you are attempting to do is achievable but no small feet!

My suggestion moving forward is to become familiar with Visual Studio and MVC first. Many books can be found on this topic. I'd recommend
[Adam Freeman's Pro ASP.net MVC](https://www.apress.com/la/book/9781430265290)

If you want to skip this step, the devsense website has numerous examples on integrating php on their website, however if you take this approach you may find progress to be painstakingly slower as they likely already assume you know how to do things in Visual Studio.

Comment: "The problem you will face..." and "On top of that you'll face..." are things I already do and have been doing for 20 years lol.  I guess the assumption was I have no clue what I am doing haha.  That is not the case.  Writing for sites has been done in pure code for years... I just want to move onto something that automates things a little more than my current setup and gives me more options which I feel VS will do.  I will look into the php issue... I know Code has php linting and all that stuff, but how well does that interact with Studio?  Sounds like that might get annoying.